# Looking up a Remote Bean, getting a EjbNamingContext in JBoss 7.1

Tags: ejb, jboss7.x, lookup, ear

I have a Maven project, in which I want to try integration-testing an EAR sub-module.
In the integration-test submodule, I do the following:

```java
Properties env;
Context ctx;

env = new Properties();

env.setProperty( "java.naming.factory.initial", "org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory");

env.setProperty(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, "org.jboss.ejb.client.naming");
env.setProperty( "java.naming.provider.url", "remote://localhost:4447");
env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "jboss-user");
env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "*******");
ctx = new InitialContext( env );


IBMPFacadeRemote bmpFacade = ( IBMPFacadeRemote ) ctx.lookup( "ejb:DeDomain-ejb-1.0-SNAPSHOT/BMPFacade!de.domain.service.IBMPFacadeRemote");
bmpFacade.executeBMPProcess( model1, model2);//model1 & model2 are some entities
```

The problem: when calling mvn integration-test it ends up with the following Exception

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.jboss.ejb.client.naming.ejb.EjbNamingContext cannot be cast to de.domain.service.IBMPFacadeRemote
```

Could someone help me to solve this problem? Are there any possibilities to integration-test this using a Local Bean (the maven project uses the failsafe-plugin)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is now hard to say what exactly solved the problem, but I will try to mention all made changes that solved the problem.

1. Added to the pom.xml the dependencies

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.jboss.as</groupId>
       <artifactId>jboss-as-ejb-client-bom</artifactId>
       <version>7.1.1.Final</version>
       <type>pom</type>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.jboss.as</groupId>
       <artifactId>jboss-as-jms-client-bom</artifactId>
       <version>7.1.1.Final</version>
       <type>pom</type>
   </dependency>
   ```
2. Changed the JNDI lookup as follows (after changing the deployed name of the EAR&EJB projects)

   ```
   IBMPFacadeRemote bmpFacade = ( IBMPFacadeRemote ) ctx.lookup( "ejb:DeDomain-ear/DeDomain-ejb//BMPFacadeBean!de.domain.service.IBMPFacadeRemote");
   ```
3. Got rid of the EJB maven plugin from the EJB Project & of some other resources, like `jndi.properties`

Probably it is worth mentioning, that the `Properties` instance remained the same as in the stated in the question.

Answer (score -1):

The JNDI Properties are looking strange for me. I was always successfull with the following Properties for JBoss:

```
java.naming.provider.url=jnp://localhost:1099
java.naming.factory.initial=org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory
java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=org.jboss.naming:org.jnp.interfaces
jnp.socket.Factory=org.jnp.interfaces.TimedSocketFactory
```

May be you should double check them.

Comment: Jboss has a nasty habbit of changing things wherever they can. If the above worked for JBoss 6, it's highly likely it's completely diferent in JBoss 7.